# connection closed by server error when getting accounts using coinbase-exchange websocket

Tags: ruby, rest, coinbase-api

I'm using the ruby coinbase-exchange gem, and I'm executing the code by copying and pasting it into irb.

This only happens when I'm running it as a websocket – when I just execute the code on its own, without the socket, it works fine.

When the following code executes,

```
accounts = Array.new(2, Array.new)
rest_api.accounts do |resp|
  accounts = resp
end
```

this error is produced:

> ```
> Coinbase::Exchange::APIError: GET https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/accounts?: connection closed by server
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/coinbase-exchange-0.1.2/lib/coinbase/exchange/adapters/em_http.rb:59:in `block in http_verb'
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/em/deferrable.rb:158:in `set_deferred_status'
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/em/deferrable.rb:198:in `fail'
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/em-http-request-1.1.5/lib/em-http/client.rb:123:in `on_error'
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/em-http-request-1.1.5/lib/em-http/client.rb:117:in `unbind'
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/em-http-request-1.1.5/lib/em-http/http_connection.rb:205:in `block in unbind'
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/em-http-request-1.1.5/lib/em-http/http_connection.rb:205:in `map'
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/em-http-request-1.1.5/lib/em-http/http_connection.rb:205:in `unbind'
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/em-http-request-1.1.5/lib/em-http/http_connection.rb:31:in `unbind'
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:1481:in `event_callback'
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:202:in `release_machine'
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:202:in `ensure in run'
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:205:in `run'
> from (irb):79
> from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
> ```

What's the problem here? How do I get around it?